# Select only specific keys in projection

Tags: mongodb

I've got a pretty simple question. Here's the data structure:

```
"_id" : "...",
"key" : "k1",
"messages" : {
  "en" : "m1en",
  "de" : "m1de"
}
```

Now I want to select only(!) those messages with "de" **as key**. Is this possible?
I know I can `find` those with `$exists : true` but that doesn't work inside projection.

The result should look like:

```
"key" : "k1",
"messages" : {
  "de" : "m1de"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation in your projection object to do that:

```js
{
    "_id": 0,
    "key": 1,
    "messages.de": 1
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to exclude all keys BUT ["de","fr"] or something like that?

Comment: Except for `_id` you can't mix includes and excludes, but you can exclude a key using `"messages.fr": 0`.

Comment: Thank you. With mongo console client it's working fine :) Now I've got an issue with my java client lib. But that's another thing.